# Change approver in Approval Process from Manager to Queue

Tags: approval-process

I have an approval process that has Manager listed as the Approver  I want to change the Approver to be a queue. How do I make this change.  I cloned the approval process and still am unable to get to the option that lets me set the Approver to a queue versus the Manager.

Comment: Is this on a custom object or a standard object? Is the queue related to the right object as I can see this option on both custom and std objects in a dev org when I try to reproduce.

Comment: This is on a custom object.  I am not able to see the options for selecting the approver that I am able to see when I create a brand new approval process.  I would prefer to not start the approval process over from scratch to get the additional approver options.

Comment: I found the options for selecting the approver appeared when I tried editing steps of an existing approval process so is that a possible option?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That worked.  I am new to this and wasn't looking at the step.